# EEPROM Pic Micro and Arduino Hex file

Tags: arduino, pic, eeprom

When retrieving the hex file from either a pic micro or arduino chip, does the hex file contain the EEPROM of that particular chip?

Does the hex file only contain the program or the program and EEPROM?

Comment: What are you using to "retrieve"?

Comment: on the pic I will use a pickit 2 for example, not sure with the Arduino probably an atmel programmer aswell

Comment: Which PIC part number? There are many of them and they behave differently.

Comment: Pic16f887 and an arduino uno

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `PIC Hex File Format` then yes, it contain EEPROM data and even more.
The PIC hex file contain: code, EEPROM data, user bytes (User ID) and configuration words.

Check also: http://www.kanda.com/blog/microcontrollers/pic-microcontrollers/pic-hex-file-format/

Comment: Thanks GJ, I ask this question because I can not find a way to protect my code on an Arduino .i.e. (stop someone from downloading the HEX and burning it on another chip). So I thought that if I can store some important variables in the EEPROM which the HEX file does "not contain" then the program wont work as expected. From that blog it seems that this will be possible with a Arduino (AVR) and not a PIC.